# Example for a claim

Tags: abstract-algebra, semigroups

If $H$ is a subsemigroup of a semigroup $S$, then it may happen that, for some $a$ and $b$ in $S$, the sets $aH$ and $bH$ don't coincide and, nonetheless, are not disjoint.

Does there exist an example for this claim?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Have you tried anything? For example, say $H=S=\Bbb Z$ with $a,b$ integers. You have a good chance picking $H=S$ and pretty much any familiar semigroup which is not a group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$1+ \mathbb N \neq 2+ \mathbb N$ and $ 1+ \mathbb N \cap 2+ \mathbb N \neq \emptyset$

Answer (score 2):

Minimal counterexample. Take $H = S = \{1, 0\}$ with the usual multiplication of integer.
Then $0H = \{0\}$ and $1H = S$.

Answer (score 1):

Take $S=(\mathbb N,\cdot)$ and $H=2\mathbb N$. Now make $a=1$ and $b=2$ (here we are considering the naturals without $0$).